# getting rid of trailing `\n` character from AJAX response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

The following errors are being displayed by the console

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: $('#cartitems').html("<span class=\'smaller cartitem_added\'>Strolgmire di culatello<\/span>\n");
$('#cartitems_count').html("7\n");
```

when being generated by:

```
$('#cartitems').html("<%= j render('cartitem_added') %>"); 
$('#cartitems_count').html("<%= j render ('cart_size') %>");
```

which is rendered server side by the partial `cartitem_added`

```
<span class='smaller cartitem_added'><%= @cartitem.article.try(:name) %></span>
```

and partial `cart_size`

```
<%= @new_cart_size %>
```

The only apparent culprit is `\n`. 
There is no hard return at the end of the partials.  If I add a hard return, each expression shows 2 `\n` characters.

What is occuring and how can this be avoided?

Comment: Which version of Rails you are using? Can you please share whats inside `application.js`?

Comment: rails 4.2.10.  there are no instructions in the application.js file aside from the requires.

Comment: Does it contain `//= require jquery`?

Comment: that is correct jquery is required.